# What languages generates bytecodes and can be load/executed in C++

Tags: c++, programming-languages, bytecode, vm-implementation

I'd like to know what languages fit this scenario:

I'm writing an application (C++) and I need to add some type of scripting support to it, but this language must be able to be "compiled".

This compilation will generate some type of "bytecode" that is not readable by humans. Then I need to be able to get this bytecode, load it inside the C++ application and execute it.

Exporting c++ application functions to the script and calling back script functions is a must.

The main idea is to extend application functionality without touching the C++ code, but it must be hard for a user to read these scripts.

What languages can I use?

Comment: So, you'd like C++ scripting, but you'd like it to be in an obscure form with a bytecode that is as obfuscated as possible - preventing your users from reverse engineering the script?

Comment: @lefticus Yes, exactly. Or anything that provides me a layer for bytecode encryption/decryption before loading/execution.

Comment: Why does it need to be hard for people to read the script bytecode? No matter what you do, if someone cares enough to want to figure it out, they will.

Comment: @GMan It's a type of "security system". It must be hard for someone to get into it. I know I can't protect the application 100%, but that's not an excuse to not protect it as hard as possible. Then you question me: so why adding scripting support? The script system will be added because it will receive A LOT of updates that will be downloaded by many consumers and written by programmers that doesn't have access to the main source code.

Comment: @WoLfulus: My point is that it serves in no way as security. Either it's so impossible to decipher that your own program can't run it, or it's readable by everyone capable of decompiling your program. The only thing obfuscation is going to do is deter those who barely cared in the first place.

Comment: @GMan Hence my answer that he may as well choose whichever language he wants to and to and internal encryption of the script.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps Brainfuck? Certainly easy to find interpreters, and much less readable than your average machine code or byte code.

Comment: aw a -1 :P well I thought it was funny anyways ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'd love to suggest [ChaiScript](http://www.chaiscript.com), but we don't have any kind of encryption or bytecode support built in.

That said, there's no reason you could not use any existing C++ scripting engine. ChaiScript, luabind, etc, could all be used if you provide your own encryption and decryption functions for feeding the script into the engine.

The one scripting engine that I know of that supports c++ and bytecode and is relatively obscure is [AngelScript](http://www.angelcode.com). They have a page on loading [pre-compiled bytecode](http://www.angelcode.com/angelscript/sdk/docs/manual/doc_adv_precompile.html).

Comment: I knew I knew you from somewhere else. I've used ChaiScript some time ago, but the project compile time goes to a level that it starts pissing me off. About AngelScript, I've worked with it too, it's an amazing script engine, but the piece that is missing is an easy and reliable way for binding C++ to the scripts and vice versa  (just like chaiscript).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [Vox](https://github.com/beelzebub/vox)* can fit your bill?

The scripts can be precompiled into portable bytecode, and is very easy to embed, with stackbased API similar to Lua:

```
// most basic embedding example
VoxVM* v = vox_open(1024);
vox_aux_seterrorhandlers(v);
vox_pushroottable();
vox_dofile(v, "somescript.vx", false, true);
vox_pop(v, 1);
vox_close(v);
```

For a more fully featured example, see [etc/minimal.cpp](https://github.com/beelzebub/vox/blob/master/etc/minimal.cpp) and [src/frontend/frontend.cpp](https://github.com/beelzebub/vox/blob/master/src/frontend/frontend.cpp)

---

* Vox is a project that i've been working on to replace Lua for personal purposes. It's based on a highly modified version of the VM of squirrel3 (but is *not* compatible with squirrel anymore!).

The syntax has also changed a little: Instead of using `<-` for new slots, it uses `:=`, to avoid ambigious syntax.

The Core is finished and ready for use in embedded projects, but the stdlib is still unfinished, since Vox is a very young project (due to that, documentation is currently lacking, but the stdlib is a good example for embedded programming, as well as the examples for general purpose scripting).

Comment: @WoLfulus It's a young project, so as long as you only rely on the core (libvox.a when built in Linux, for example), you shouldn't have to worry about stability, as the core is finished as of now, and changes will only add functionality, but not remove any.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use [LLVM](http://llvm.org/). LLVM's intermediate representation can be stored in bytecode format. You will need to use an existing front-end for a scripting language or develop your own front-end. Your C++ application can load the bytecode file and JIT it.
[Here](http://llvm.org/ProjectsWithLLVM/) is a list of existing projects based on LLVM. You might find there a solution which fits your needs.

Comment: Its easy to create the front end? Is there any example for using that? Using LLVM doesn't seems to be a trivial task.

Comment: Creating a front-end for LLVM requires a considerable amount of work, but you should consider using one of the existing ones pointed by the link above.

Comment: I disagree, LLVM is certainly not intended to be used for scripting, as this is what OP seems to want. And it's true, embedding LLVM is not trivial, since it's simply not made for that. It's more useful if you wanted to write a compiler/interpreter. Besides, LLVM's il is more like a highlevel assembler.

Answer (score 1):

LuaJIT is a nice, quick Lua interpreter, that JITs Lua into native machine code. LuaJIT bytecode is platform independent, unlike regular Lua.

Take a look for yourself:
http://luajit.org/luajit.html
http://luajit.org/extensions.html